# Replace Value from one column based on a condition from another column [Power Query]

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

Hello this is my first post!

I'm trying to replace the word "OTROS" from the column `Origen` based on the condition that the column `Marca` has the value "X-1000".
I'm following this video: https://youtu.be/XpZTPEBHQOY?t=81

However when I try to execute the following code in the Power Query bar nothing happens

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type", 
each [Origen], 
each if [Marca] = "X-1000" then "CHINA" else [Origen], 
Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Origen"})
```

[image: Table image]

I tried refreshing and doing it again but nothing happens.
Thanks a lot in advanced for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works perfectly, it is how you are using it

updated answer :: Based on comments your column has a space in the column name

You needed to use [#"Marca "] instead of [Marca]

change your code to

```
let
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\RAD\Downloads\Parque Vehicular.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=9, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Año Inscripción", Int64.Type}, {"Mes Inscripción", Int64.Type}, {"Año Entrada", Int64.Type}, {"Descripción Clase", type text}, {"Tipo", type text}, {"Año Fabricación", Int64.Type}, {"Origen", type text}, {"Marca ", type text}, {"Cantidad", Int64.Type}}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type", each [Origen], each if [#"Marca "] = "X-1000" then "CHINA" else [Origen], Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Origen"})
in #"Replaced Value"
```

Comment: Since the first option is still not working for me I'm trying to do it through the advanced editor option like you said below the  `#"Changed Type" =` like so `#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",
    each [Origen],
    each if [Marca] = "X-1000" then "CHINA" else [Origen], Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Origen"})
in #"Replaced Value"` but in the last `in` I get this error **"Token Eof expected"**

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a complete copy of your code copied from home ... advanced editor

Comment: The code posted in comment above works perfectly. So there is something wrong with the rest of your code. Is there a comma like there should be at the end of the row above the #"Replaced Value"= row?

Comment: I edited the question for the code from the advanced editor... Is it missing a comma?

Comment: With your updated answer I don't have the error anymore. But still the values are not being replaced, same as with the first method that wasn't working for me. I did this video to show how it doesn't do anything. I think the problem is something  else https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mk8Dkh3RD40

Comment: Filter the Marca column using the drop down arrow on top of that column.  Select and choose only [X] X-1000. Then look at the code generated. What is in the ""? Does it say [Marca] = "X-1000" or something else?  Im going to guess there are more charactes in there that are not being shown

Comment: It just says "X-1000"
`= Table.SelectRows(#"Replaced Value", each ([#"Marca "] = "X-1000"))`

Comment: So there is your answer. The column is not named Marca it is named Marca with a space after it.  change the code to be :   #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type", each [Origen], each if [#"Marca "] = "X-1000" then "CHINA" else [Origen], Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Origen"})   This assumes the Origen column is named Origen.  You can test it yourself the same way for spaces